# how to view a textview when i scroll?

Tags: android, scroll

I have a listview and a textview, but the listview takes all the screen. what can i do so when i scroll down i can be able to see my textview?
I have this on a vertical LinearLayout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_settings"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_settings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="@string/mail_text"
    android:textColor="@color/Gray"/>
```

Comment: show me the whole script of xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace listview code with following.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_settings"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your parent layout Relative Layout, which is Linear at the moment, and in your `TextView` write this line `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and in your ListView,add this property `android:layout_above="@+id/txt_settings"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_settings"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFF000"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Your Text"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**Activity.xml**:

```
 <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_settings"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Tes"
        ></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Haven't tested the code yet but I put a scrollview. The **listview** should be scrollable and in the end show the **TextView**. Plus, you can manage the proportions dealing with the `layout_weight=x` parameter.

Comment: this error shows: The vertically scrolling ScrollView should not contain another vertically scrolling widget(ListView)

Comment: You're right, I'll update my answer soon. Though, the answer is how @Yousef khan described